# Alternative to Lagrange multipliers

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

We want to maximise $f(x,y)$ under the constraint $g(x,y)= 0$. Instead of using Lagrange multipliers, can we just set the dot product of the $\nabla f \cdot{ (1,dy/dx)}$ under the constraint $g$ to equal $0$. This should work because the vector $(1,dy/dx)$ is parallel to the contour $g(x,y) =0$ and perpendicular to the $\nabla{ f}$.

Comment: Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: The question is what is $dy\over dx$ in your text.

Comment: Under the constraint

Answer (score 0):

This mostly works, but what if ${dy\over dx}$ doesn’t exist at some point on the constraint curve? This isn’t all that far out a possibility: consider the points at which $x^2+y^2=1$ intersects the $x$-axis, for instance.

You either need to consider these cases separately, or use a slightly different formulation if you wish to avoid introducing a Lagrange multiplier: if $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ are parallel, then $$\begin{vmatrix}{\partial f\over\partial x} & {\partial f\over\partial y} \\ {\partial g\over\partial x} & {\partial g\over\partial y}\end{vmatrix} = 0.$$ That is, use a cross product instead of a dot product.

Comment: I believe the issue is that you have found extreme for all possible contours of g but you.dont know which corresponds to which

Comment: @Dis-integrating I don’t understand your comment. Your method overlooks potential solutions and requires dealing with special cases. Using a determinant (cross product) instead doesn’t. There’s no question of “which corresponds to which” that I can see. The system of equations to be solved includes $g(x,y)=0$ either way.

Comment: You are correct. Also, if we use this method to try to find solution in x for example then you have a problem. You do not know which of those solutions corresponds to g=0 and there is no way of checking as far as I can tell. This is what I meant

Comment: As the condition imposed works in general to maximise f under g = c an arbitrary constant

Comment: @Dis-integrating The system of equations that I’ve presented here works just fine regardless of which variable you solve for first. The constraint equations must, of course, also be satisfied, but that’s no different than the situation with the classic Lagrange multiplier method: you still have to pick out those solutions of $\nabla f=\lambda\nabla g$ that satisfy $g(x,y)=0$.

Comment: @Dis-integrating Any necessary constant can be absorbed into $g$, so the constraint can always be expressed in the form $g(x,y)=0$. That way, setting the partial derivative of the Lagrangian w/r $\lambda$ to zero recovers the constraint equation, and the entire system of equations, including constraints, can be expressed in the compact form $\nabla\mathcal L=0$.